# frame not recognized

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver

Selenium 2 webdriver for C# is unable to locate the frame "nav_bottom"
but it can recognize the frame "top" .I am testing in Firefox 12.
markup is like below..top most frameset does not have id or name attribute

```
<frameset>
    <frame id ="top">
    <frameset id="bottom">
        <frame id="nav_bottom">
```

I resolved this issue by troubleshooting which frames are visible at given time. thank you for your help.

```
    ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> frames1 = driver.FindElements(By.TagName("frame"));

    Console.Write("total frames " + frames1.Count);

    foreach ( IWebElement frame in frames1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("focus is on main frame  " + frame.GetAttribute("id"));
        }
```

Comment: How are you currently attempting to find the frame? Post your code?

Comment: //focus back to main frame
driver.SwitchTo().DefaultContent();

wait.Until(x => x.FindElement(By.TagName("frame").Name("ek_nav_bottom")));
driver.SwitchTo().Frame("ek_nav_bottom");

Comment: That does seem like a safer way to do things (in your edit). I was thinking you may have been trying to access one by a pre-determined id. Good to hear it's fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need the driver to switch focus to the frame first. Try fiddling around with:

```
driver.SwitchTo().Frame(the frame IWebElement);
```

Try each frame as an IWebElement, hope this helps.

Comment: I was able to resolve the issue by troubleshooting which frames are visible. There were several frames and iframes.